# Is there a black version of the chicken suit, without having to paint it?

Tags: pc, fable-3

In Fable-3, are there multiple ways to get the chicken suit, ending in multiple default suit colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to get a [chicken suit](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Chicken_Suit_%28Fable_III%29):

- [Brightwall Village Quest](http://fable.wikia.com/wiki/Chicken_Chaser)
- Shops

The chicken suit purchased will always be the same color